# update multiple columns in mysql database using $_GET

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update 3 fields in a row in 3 columns but I don't know how to do it. I already searched google and searcedh here but couldn't find any solution for it. I want to change `title`, `paragraph` and `category` of a blog post using `$_GET` using this way:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<div class="middle">
  <div class="content" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="context" style="width:100%">
      <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $txt = $_POST['txt'];
$query = ("UPDATE tbl_post SET title='$title' WHERE id=$id");
$query = ("UPDATE tbl_post SET txt='$txt' WHERE id=$id");
```

when I use only one of `$_title` or `$_txt`, it works. But I couldn't find a way to update both fields together and couldnt update category selection.

full code of update.php page :

```
<?php require_once("config.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<div class="middle">
  <div class="content" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="context" style="width:100%">
     <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $txt = $_POST['txt'];
   $query = ("UPDATE tbl_post SET title='$title' WHERE id=$id");
    $query = ("UPDATE tbl_post SET txt='$txt' WHERE id=$id");
    $query = ("UPDATE tbl_post SET cat='$cat' WHERE id=$id");

mysql_query($query,$con);
header("location:insert.php");
exit(); 
        }
?>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <?php

      $id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_post` WHERE(id=$id)";
$res = mysql_query($query,$con);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
?>
        <p>عنوان مطلب</p>
        <input type="text" name="title" style="width:200px; border:1px solid #8C8C8C" value="<?php echo $rows['title'] ?>">
        <p>محتوای پست</p>
        <textarea name="txt" style="width:300px"><?php echo $rows['txt'] ?></textarea>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <p>دسته بندی</p>
        <select name="cat" style="width:200px">
          <?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_cat` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
$res = mysql_query($query,$con);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)){


?>
          <option value="<?php echo $rows ['id'] ?>"><?php echo $rows ['name'] ?></option>
         </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="" value="ثبت در دیتابیس" style="width:200px; margin-top:15px;">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>
```

and insert.php :

```
<?php require_once("config.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
<div class="middle">
  <div class="content" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="context" style="width:100%">


    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $cat = $_POST['cat'];
        $txt = $_POST['txt'];
        echo 'title = '.$title.'<br>'.'category ='.$cat.'<br>'.'txt = '.$txt;
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_post(`title`,`txt`,`cat_id`) VALUES  ('$title','$txt','$cat')";   
mysql_query($query,$con);
header("location:insert.php");
exit(); 
        }
?>

 <form action="" method="post">
        <p>عنوان مطلب</p>
        <input type="text" name="title" style="width:200px; border:1px solid #8C8C8C;">
        <p>دسته بندی</p>
        <select name="cat" style="width:200px">
          <?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_cat` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
$res = mysql_query($query,$con);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)){


?>
          <option value="<?php echo $rows ['id'] ?>"><?php echo $rows ['name'] ?></option>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <p>محتوای پست</p>
        <textarea name="txt" style="width:300px"></textarea>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="" value="ثبت در دیتابیس" style="width:200px; margin-top:15px;">



      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: U dont need to run 2 queries to update 1 table u can do it like this `UPDATE table SET this='$that', abc='$xyz' WHERE sun='$moon'`

Comment: "I want to update 3 fields..." I only see 2: `title` and `txt`. What is the third?

Comment: Where is the code that executes the query?

Comment: If you do each field in separate queries, you have to execute the query between the `$query` assignments. My guess is you're executing the query at the end, so it only does the last `$query` that you assign.

Comment: full code added .title and txt updated.but  still couldn't update category.

Answer (score 2):

Combine all the fields into a single query:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$txt = $_POST['txt'];
$cat = $_POST['cat'];

$query = "UPDATE tbl_post SET title='$title', txt = '$txt', cat = '$cat' WHERE id = $id";
```

Also, you should switch to parametrized queries instead of substituting into the SQL; this means using `PDO` or `mysqli`. Otherwise you need to escape the input data. See

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thanks.first problem resolved.problem was only (,) after '$title' !! but '$cat' still doesn't work and i couldn't update category selection(drop down menu),in database.

Comment: Hi, your problem that the $query is variable, and not you don't call query function for db, then query valui is: "UPDATE tbl_post SET cat='$cat' WHERE id=$id"

you can see mysql update syntax and working description: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

@Barmar's answer good.